# Failed to update in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: updates

I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS and ran the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

it gives the following error:

```
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
now what should i do now?
```

Comment: internet connection  is slow

Comment: That would most likely be the problem. Apt-get can't connect tot he servers to fetch the packages.

Comment: i was facing the same issue. This was because of Internet connection.

Comment: May be having a reboot solve the problem...

Comment: @user267144: Try to run `wget -d URL` for requested URLs to debug your problem. E.g. `wget -d http://in.archive.ubuntu.com`

Comment: May be a DNS issue. Can you `ping in.archive.ubuntu.com`?